# Android: background service for Chrome in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome

I want to build an android app that trigger notifications or some kind of floating window (similar to the one that Truecaller uses when you copy a phone number) when you enter a specific url in your browser (Chrome or similar).

Is that possible? If so how?

Any help would be greatly helpful!